# Sharing session with session state server

Tags: windows, iis-7, cluster-computing, session-state

I'm trying to setup two Windowz boxes (`win1`, `win2`) between a varnish round robin loab balancer.

Session state for the application is both configured as "State server" pointing on a third machine (`x.y.w.z`). Calling `telnet x.y.w.z 42424` is ok from both `win1` and `win2`.
Al machines have same OS version.
Both machines have the same machine key [image]

I've dropped in ans aspx debugging page copied from http://pardini.net/blog/2011/02/17/the-ultimate-asp-net-session-state-debugging-tool/ and it shows two different machine keys.

[image]

i can see that `AppDomainAppId` is different; how can I change it?
What is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in [Sharing session state over multiple ASP.NET applications with ASP.NET state server](http://weblogs.asp.net/lichen/sharing-session-state-over-multiple-asp-net-applications-with-asp-net-state-server) I've added a hook into Global.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Cfg;
using NHibernate.Context;
using NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.Reflection;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Global
/// </summary>
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
  public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory;

private static Configuration _configuration;

public override void Init()
{
    base.Init();
    foreach (string moduleName in this.Modules)
    {
        string appName = "MYAPPNAME";
        IHttpModule module = this.Modules[moduleName];
        SessionStateModule ssm = module as SessionStateModule;
        if (ssm != null)
        {
            FieldInfo storeInfo = typeof(SessionStateModule).GetField("_store", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            SessionStateStoreProviderBase store = (SessionStateStoreProviderBase)storeInfo.GetValue(ssm);
            if (store == null) //In IIS7 Integrated mode, module.Init() is called later
            {
                FieldInfo runtimeInfo = typeof(HttpRuntime).GetField("_theRuntime", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                HttpRuntime theRuntime = (HttpRuntime)runtimeInfo.GetValue(null);
                FieldInfo appNameInfo = typeof(HttpRuntime).GetField("_appDomainAppId", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                appNameInfo.SetValue(theRuntime, appName);
            }
            else
            {
                Type storeType = store.GetType();
                if (storeType.Name.Equals("OutOfProcSessionStateStore"))
                {
                    FieldInfo uribaseInfo = storeType.GetField("s_uribase", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                    uribaseInfo.SetValue(storeType, appName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
(...)
```